# App data not refreash after I'm update the data in real-time database in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I created a database in firebase (real-time database).
I make an API calls for get, post, put and delete. In firebase the data update correctly, but in my react app only after refreash the page I see the changes. I tried to solve it by calling the 'get' function after post, put and delete functions (for fetch the data again) but it doesn't work perfect and I'm sure there is a better way to do it (maybe with useEffect).
I'm using redux for state management.

My code:

```
const getFromDB = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('MY URL');
    const data = await response.json();
    const loadedData = [];
    for(const key in data){
        loadedData.push({
            id: key,
            title: data[key].title,
            description: data[key].description,
            status: data[key].status,
            critical: data[key].critical
        });
    }
    setDataArray(loadedData);
    dispatch(getData(loadedData));
};

const postToDB = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('MY URL', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: titleInput,
            description: descriptionInput,
            status: statusInput,
            critical: criticalInput
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    getFromDB(); //call again get function to fetch the updated data from firebase
};
```

I would be very grateful for any help

Comment: Where is the code which _reads_ the data from the redux store? If the state is updated and you dispatch the action, the store should be updated and any component which depends on those values should be re rendered.

Comment: Try to console.log dataArray, if it has the right data then create useSelector state from redux getData and log it too. What are your results?

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai This is how I read data from redux:
`const dataRed = useSelector((state) => state.DataReducer);`
So when I get the data from firebase I store it in DataReducer and then use it in my component like {dataRed.data.title}.

Comment: @Phaki I console.log dataArray and getData. Them both show me the updated array with the data. To be honest, after I strated to use redux I don't realy need dataArray because I have the getData state. For example to explain better, if I delete manually data from the database in firebase I would expect to see the change in my react app in real time and this is not happens (only after refreash).

Comment: In other words, I want to call getFromDB() function to fetch the data in every change on my json database.

Comment: It appears to me that you want the component to react to the changes in the data base. But that will only happen if you actually implement it. Im not sure on the specifics of this data base but i would think it would be something like this. The database, should have some call back of when items are added (from some other process). Now you can use that callback to dispatch to store and your component can get data from the redux store. It isnt clear with the info you provided that you are expecting this sort of an interaction.

Comment: @EmmanuelPonnudurai Thank you for the answer. I understand what you say, this is what I really expect happen. But, with any change in the database my component doesn't re-render. For example if in my useEffect I call the fetch get data, it will call it at the first running, bug after the change in the database it will not enter again to the useEffect and the data will not update in the component.

Comment: OK. Why don't you provide the code that you have ( a simplified form) and then we can suggest? But one point I'd like to add is. How would the component know when something changed in the database? You must tell it. And they way you tell it is via props and so the component can then react to such changes. Like I said, pls provide more info if you want better assistance.